# Default directory when navigating to a bat (or any) file

Tags: java, batch-file, testng

I have a run-tests.bat file as in the following (provided to us).  This bat file is in a directory along with a lot of other files and is zipped.  It is a standalone testng directory.  In addition to this file, in the directory are subdirectorys lib/ and drivers/ and lib/ does have testng:

```
@ECHO OFF@ECHO OFF

SET javacmd=
SET javacp=-classpath ".;lib/*"
SET jvmparams=-Dwebdriver.ie.driver="drivers/IEDriverServer.exe" - Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="drivers/chromedriver.exe"

IF "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    SET javacmd=java
) ELSE (
    SET javacmd="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
)

for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('%javacmd% -fullversion 2^>^&1')     do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
IF %jver% LSS 17000 (
    ECHO Java version is not supported. Please install Java 1.7 or greater.
    GOTO RETURN 
)

%javacmd% %javacp% %jvmparams% org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

:RETURN

IF -%1-==-- (
    PAUSE
)
```

When I run this on my machine it works fine.  I needed to copy it to a shared directory so some other people could run it.  I copied it to a shared directory and tests it and it ran fine.  I navigated with the file explorer, and double clicked.

When I had the tester do it from his machine, the cmd window would just come up and disappear.  I put a bunch of pauses in it to see where it was failing.  The %jver% is 17045 so it made it past that line.  It failed at the %javacmd% command and said it could not find (or load) org.testng.TESTNG.  It found it fine when I ran it from my machine but not from his.

My only thought is that when I double click on the .bat file it somehow CD's me to the correct directory, but leaves him in his directory so that SET 
*javacp=-classpath ".;lib/*"* sets lib/*.* in his own directory rather than in the directory that is unzipped.  I tried to figure out when you click on a .bat file whether it CDs you to a directory or not but could not find it out.

So is my theory for why it is not working correct, or is there some other reason I am not seeing?  I verified my dos version and his are the same, 6.1.7601, and we are both using Windows 7 and he has Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double clicking a `.bat` or `.cmd` script file causes that script runs usually 
either in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` or in `%SystemRoot%\system32` starting directory. I'd try next

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
echo "%~f0" script started in "%CD%"
pushd "%~dp0"
echo "%~0" script now run in "%CD%"
pause 

rem continue here with your code:
SET javacmd=
…
```

Explanation:

- `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions`: although Command Extensions are enabled by default, this can be disabled or switched off, see [CMD shell](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) or `cmd /?`. Right ensure…
- `"%~f0"`, `"%~dp0"` Parameter Extensions: see [Command Line Arguments](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) or `call /?`.
- `pushd "%~dp0"`: [change the current directory/folder](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) including disk drive, see also `pushd /?`.